# Angular 4 doesn't see installed packages with npm

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm starting my adventure with ASP.NET Core and Angular 4.
I started Angular template project in VisualStudio.

I created some basic pages and tried to install ngx-datatable module with npm.
I've done everything from demo
[ngx-databtable Documentation](https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/introduction/getting-started.html)

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^10.2.3",
    "@types/ui-grid": "0.0.38",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.6",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
}
```

After running with Debug -> Run without debugging
I got such error:

```
NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'rows' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-datatable'.
1. If 'ngx-datatable' is an Angular component and it has 'rows' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-datatable' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<div class="col-md-12 tab">
<div>
<ngx-datatable [ERROR ->][rows]="rows"
[columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
"): ng:///AppModuleShared/WorkersComponent.html@11:23
Can't bind to 'columns' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-datatable'.
1. If 'ngx-datatable' is an Angular component and it has 'columns' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-datatable' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<div>
<ngx-datatable [rows]="rows"
[ERROR ->][columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
</div>
"): ng:///AppModuleShared/WorkersComponent.html@12:23
'ngx-datatable' is not a known element:
```

Could anyone suggest what may be the reason of that and what are the most common mistakes, which leads to such error?

Thanks in advance!

**============== EDIT ========================**

I've already imported NgxDatatableModule like it was in Demo, despite this the error is occuring.

My AppModule file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module.shared';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppModuleShared,
        NgxDatatableModule
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function getBaseUrl() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}
```

And view in which I try to use this table:

```
<div>
    <ngx-datatable [rows]="rows"
                   [columns]="columns">
    </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

And controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'workers',
    templateUrl: './workers.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./workers.component.css', '../app.module.css']
})
export class WorkersComponent { 
    rows = [
        { name: 'Austin', gender: 'Male', company: 'Swimlane' },
        { name: 'Dany', gender: 'Male', company: 'KFC' },
        { name: 'Molly', gender: 'Female', company: 'Burger King' },
    ];
    columns = [
        { prop: 'name' },
        { name: 'Gender' },
        { name: 'Company' }
    ];
}
```

Should I change anything in default config in order to move files from imported ngxDataTable to wwwroot?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the `ngx-datatable` using `npm install` you have to add this to your app module as well to use its component

As the error message says it is not able to bind row and known properites to `ngx-datatable`

```
Can't bind to 'rows' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-datatable'.
```

It means its unable to find `ngx-datatable` directive.

So import `NgxDatatableModule` in your app module and it will make available all the component and directive in your app.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NgxDatatableModule, BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've already imported NgxDatatableModule despite that the error is occuring. I've updated main question.

Comment: No, it's a part of the AppModule.